# Does Android version matter when learning Android development?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, version

I am going to enrol on a course to learning Android Development. There it says it ***"write apps for Android 8 Oreo with Kotlin"***

But Android 11 is already out there.
So is the course worth it in 2021. Or Android version does not matter.

It will be really helpful if you can share your advice.
If you have any confusion feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes it is worth it. Important topics like viewmodel, Room, WorkerManager will be covered. You might need to learn compose on your own later on, but xml is still okay. There are free courses which will teach you everything up to date for free from google. These are called codelabs. I learned development with these courses and passed the official certification on 1. attempt

Comment: does codelab meet the professional standard

Comment: Codelabs are made by the team making the software. For example check this databinding codelab. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#codelabs It should help you understand everything about 2 way databinding. All codelabs of Android https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=android

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=android
All codelabs for android.
https://developer.android.com/courses/kotlin-android-fundamentals/overview
Free Bootcamp from udacity

What do you mean professional standard?
These Codelabs are written by the teams developing the APIs like Maps.

In my oppinion I had a better understanding from doing the codelabs then enrolling in any classes, if you are more of a hands on learner like me codelabs are worth the time.

Comment: I am more comfortable with video courses. than documentation when learning new tech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, the answer to your question is **yes it will be helpful.**

at the end of the day, it depends upon your app's target audience. For example, if you go to Android Studio and make a new project, they ask you to select a minimum SDK.
So for comparison's sake let me give you the list.

- Android 4.1 (Your app will run on approximately 99.8% of devices)
- Android 4.4 (Your app will run on approximately 98.1% of devices)
- Android 5.0 (Your app will run on approximately 94.1% of devices)
- Android 5.1 (Your app will run on approximately 92.3% of devices)
- Android 6.0 (Your app will run on approximately 84.9% of devices)
- Android 7.0 (Your app will run on approximately 73.7% of devices)
- Android 8.0 (Your app will run on approximately 60.8% of devices)
- Android 9.0 (Your app will run on approximately 39.5% of devices)
- Android 10.0 (Your app will run on approximately 8.2% of devices)
- Android 11.0 (Your app will run on approximately < 1% of devices)

So, it's a trade-off, with a newer version you'll get more features and you can offer more features but at the same time, you'll lose users.

As of Android 8.0, all the features in 8.0 will be, I guess, included in the Android 11.0. So, you can learn 8.0 and shift to 11.0 as per your needs.

Also, on May 7, 2019, Google announced Kotlin as its official programming language for Android Development. Many apps such as Zomato, dropbox, weChat, Netflix, Trello, Slacks, etc have shifted to Kotlin.

key features would be view-model, Kotlin Coroutines, Live-data, Room Database, and Flows are all included in Android 8 as well as 11.

So, as far as basics are concerned it's a THUMBS UP for the course.
Also, if you are keener on learning Android, go through [Android Kotlin Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/courses/kotlin-android-fundamentals/overview)

Answer (score 1):

It is a seemingly good to have thing to start with latest version since they bring up quite a number of changes over time. If that is posisble, my suggestion would be to start with the latest Android 10/11 courses.

On the other hand, any sort of Software development is based on the fundamental understanding of the platform. Hence if the latest courses are not that good, to learn basics, the Android 8 course should also be fine. Basically, anything that teaches you how to build Android apps, in general, is enough.

Happy learning and I hope you have a lot of fun while doing so!

Comment: After I learn Android development based on version-8, will I be able to teach myself newer versions

Comment: Yes definitely. I had learnt starting from Around Android 6/8. And I think I am able to catch up and stay updated with latest changes as well. Once you "understand" things, everything else is just a mapping of "used to be X in Android 8 and now Y in latest one".

Comment: I have sorted a course. Can I share its link here. So that you(experienced developer only) can review and tell if it is worth learning in 2021.

Comment: Yeah sure, I can take a quick look at what is covered. :)

Comment: This seems nice - https://www.udemy.com/course/android-kotlin-developer/

Comment: what about the other course??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235336/discussion-between-dron-bhattacharya-and-pranav-jadhav).

Comment: please review the other course

Answer (score 1):

There are changes between android 8 and android 11. One popular one is the external storage and how it's accessed. You can go ahead with your course, a lot of things hasn't changed yet and it's easy to adjust to these changes.

Comment: I have sorted a course. Can I share its link here. So that you(experienced developer only) can review and tell if it is worth learning in 2021.

Comment: You can share the link

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/course/android-oreo-kotlin-app-masterclass/
And https://www.udemy.com/course/android-kotlin-developer/

Comment: I saw AsyncTask (it's deprecated). you were introduced to SQLite database which is okay, but no mention of Room database anywhere. It's a good course, whatever you didn't learn there, you can use the official documentation and codelab to learn. Stack overflow is also here for you.

Comment: what about the other course???

Comment: I checked both of them (except that of Kotlin since i don't program with Kotlin yet), they're more than 90% up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it matter the most , google has deprecated lot of functionalities above Android 10 which works for older devices. You need to set target SDK as latest version so lint will give you warning of deprecation.